# Example Dashboard Widget, Cancel not working

Tags: plugin-development, dashboard, api

Working from the Code from Wordpress API Dashboard Widget Example: 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Example_Dashboard_Widget

I am able to build the plugin, the number updates perfectly when I click configure and then submit. Just one issue, if I click Cancel, to cancel updating the number, the number is set to blank (NULL). Even if I have a number in the input box.

How would I go about ensuring that the example number is left as it is and not updated to NULL when cancel is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, maybe I asked it too soon ... took a look at it again and gave myself a slap for being so stupid. The widget-config.php is set to update when the page loads so every time it loaded the page it updated the 'example_number' option all you need to do is add if(isset($_POST['submit'])) to it.